# Why is 눈 pronounced the way it is?

Tags: pronunciation

The word 눈 is pronounced differently to what I expect it would, with regards to the first consonant. Fluent Forever mentions that pronunciation rules for Korean are fairly complex, but I don't understand this particular case, and I couldn't find anything by doing a search. What rule explains its pronunciation?

Link to [krdict](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?ParaWordNo=72704&nationCode=6&nation=eng&captchaNumber=&comment_user_name=&wordComment=&viewTypes=on&myViewWord=72704) entry, where the first consonant sounds more like a "d" sound rather than an "n". Some entries on forvo also have this pronunciation.

Comment: I've never noticed anything odd about it - what are you finding strange?

Comment: @topomorto edited.

Comment: The dictionary link you provided shows it as [눈] (starting with an "n" sound). Perhaps you're talking about eye [눈] vs snow [눈ː], where the latter has a elongated vowel?

Comment: Yay, _denasalization_!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The phenomenon you're hearing has been described not just in [academic](http://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/1324541/1/1324541.pdf) [literature](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/denasalized-nasals.html) but also in more modern [learners' guides](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhf9NWKHjqE) to the Korean language. It is an example of *initial denasalisation*. Basically, the nasals ㅁ and ㄴ, phonemically /m/ and /n/ respectively, tend to denasalise to a heavily voiced [b] and [d] in initial position, and especially before ㅜ /u/.

This was [reported as far back as 1924](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/denasalized-nasals.html) by [Daniel Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Jones_(phonetician)) himself no less, with this phenomenon happening before /u/. It seems to have generalised now. The [2011 study](http://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/1324541/1/1324541.pdf) showed that they are perceived as nasal consonants by Korean speakers but as non-nasal /b/ and /d/ by English speakers.