# How to pronounce "나, 너" etc. correctly

Tags: pronunciation, hangul, spoken-korean, south-korean

When watching Korean dramas, I've often heard 나, 너 pronounced as either "na, no" or "da, do". Isn't it associated with the "n" sound?

Have I misheard or is it OK to pronounce in both ways?

Comment: Who do you hear talking like this? Do you have any links? There is a style of talking sometimes used by women called 코소리 ('nose-sound') in which words are pronounced in a more nasal way, which could cause ㄴ to sound a little more like ㄷ to non-Korean ears...

Comment: @topomorto Is that so? May be that's why I heard like that. I don't really have any links. I've just heard in Korean dramas. Can't remember exactly where but I've heard it several times.

Comment: 나 is pronounced as the `a` is shan't, 너 as the sound of `o` in hot, it wouldn't be pronounced as a `d` which which would use ㄷ instead

Comment: @user17915 Yeah, that's what confused me too. Since there's a separate character for "d", I was wondering the reason for the pronunciation I heard.

Comment: @Curiousity 'n' and 'd' aren't always such different sounds even in English - if you try pinching your nose and saying 'no', it might sound a bit like 'dough'. Not sure if that kind of thing might be what you're hearing... like 'n' but in an unfamiliar intonation.

Comment: Apparently that's a known phenomenon for Korean nasals (ㄴ/ㅁ): https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/why-is-%EB%88%88-pronounced-the-way-it-is

Comment: I recommend this site 'https://ko.forvo.com/'. It would help.

Comment: https://youtu.be/zhf9NWKHjqE like in this video said, it's neither. I recommend to watch this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have misheard. Koreans speak very fast, and I understand why many foreigners will hear the pronunciations wrong.

It is **NEVER** OK to pronounce 나, 너 as "da, deo".

By the way, 너, 노 are of different pronunciations, in case you don't know.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. :) BTW, 너, 노 are pronounced as "o" (as in "top") and "o" with a stretch (as in "coal") right? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yep, great to know you know

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by "da, deo".

Standard Korean "ㄷ" is not voiced very much at the beginning of words, British English "d" is weakly voiced, Castilian Spanish "d" is very strongly voiced and can get softened ("lenited") into a voiced fricative sound.

Standard Korean "ㄴ" *can* be weakly denasalised, as said in the [link in the comment above](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/why-is-%EB%88%88-pronounced-the-way-it-is).

> The phenomenon you're hearing has been described not just in [academic](http://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/1324541/1/1324541.pdf) [literature](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/denasalized-nasals.html) but also in more modern [learners' guides](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhf9NWKHjqE) to the Korean language. It is an example of *initial denasalisation*.

What happens when you denasalise an /n/? It turns into a heavily voiced /d/. This is close to the /d/ that you'll find in (at the beginning of words in) Spanish, Portuguese, Italian. But it's never the same as ㄷ in Korean in the same position. That's why the ears of native Korean speakers don't get confused between the consonants represented by ㄷ and ㄴ.