# What's the correct pronunciation of 몰라요?

Tags: pronunciation

I know the hangul ㅁ is equivalent to "m",
but I've also heard it sounds more like "b"

This is based on anecdotal observation where the former is usually the case in song lyrics and the latter in drama, reality shows, etc.

Which is correct? Or maybe a better question would be which is the norm?

Is this something influenced by accents?

EDIT for examples:

ㅁ as "b":

> 0:53
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_nZ1RwvPmE

ㅁ as "m":

> 0:14 
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SdzLl-XpJt0

Comment: Korean alphabet pronunciation chart: https://blog.naver.com/mh7785/221352096601

Comment: Where is it pronounced as 'b'? Do you have any references (like name of show where it was possibly pronounced as 'b', or a video link)?

Comment: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/why-is-%EB%88%88-pronounced-the-way-it-is/2746#2746 - same phenomenon on a different word

Comment: @Michaelyus the answer in that question clarified it. Thanks!

Comment: @user17915 I'll try to look for contrasting examples and make an edit.

Comment: Hi JFox. If you think that answer is also the answer to the question, we can close this question as a 'duplicate' if you think it's appropriate? (Still a good question!)

Comment: I think instead of the question being a duplicate, the answer covered both that and this question... @Michaelyus can post an answer with that link and some explanation and I would gladly accept it.

Comment: Interestingly, [a Korean](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1X7NxCy1Sps), who speaks in the Busan dialect in daily life, sensed the same phenomenon after learning some English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quote from my answer to the question "[Why is 눈 pronounced the way it is?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/why-is-%EB%88%88-pronounced-the-way-it-is/2746#2746)"

> The phenomenon you're hearing has been described not just in [academic](http://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/1324541/1/1324541.pdf) [literature](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/denasalized-nasals.html) but also in more modern [learners' guides](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhf9NWKHjqE) to the Korean language. It is an example of *initial denasalisation*. Basically, the nasals ㅁ and ㄴ, phonemically /m/ and /n/ respectively, tend to denasalise to a heavily voiced [b] and [d] in initial position, and especially before ㅜ /u/.
>
> This was [reported as far back as 1924](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/denasalized-nasals.html) by [Daniel Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Jones_(phonetician)) himself no less, with this phenomenon happening before /u/. It seems to have generalised now. The [2011 study](http://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/1324541/1/1324541.pdf) showed that they are perceived as nasal consonants by Korean speakers but as non-nasal /b/ and /d/ by English speakers.

Also, there *is* some [regional variation](https://www.indiana.edu/%7Eiulcwp/wp/article/viewFile/08-01/37): 경기도 (Seoul and around Seoul) has a much greater extent of denasalisation than 경상도 (Busan and Daegu etc.) where nasality is retained. However, there is also a considerable [generational difference](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/icphs-proceedings/ICPhS2015/Papers/ICPHS0845.pdf); older Busan speakers seem to never denasalise, whereas younger Busan speakers 40-70%.

Answer (score -1):

No in both videos that you've given links to, 몰라요 sounds the same. There is no (and there should not be) 'b' sound. The pronunciation for this is 'mol-la-yo'.