# Why does ㄴ sometimes sound like ㄷ (first position), such as in 너의?

Tags: pronunciation

Why is "너의" pronounced "deo-e"? I hear a very strong and clear "d" sound, stronger than an English 'd' in the following video (1:53, but it's already embedded in the link): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHqiUUacIXQ&t=113s

She appears to be a native Korean speaker. I'm sorry that it could be I'm just hearing things, but I swear that's what I hear -- I'm a native English speaker. It's confusing. Is it the way that "ㄴ" is pronounced much different than the way an English "n" is pronounced, such as tongue position, etc.?

I heard 너의 pronunciation on other websites including Google Translate and Forvo, and I hear a very clear "n" sound. Maybe it could be her microphone, her dialect, or my ears.

Comment: related questions: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/4872/whats-the-correct-pronunciation-of-%EB%AA%B0%EB%9D%BC%EC%9A%94/4874#4874, https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/why-is-%EB%88%88-pronounced-the-way-it-is/2746#2746

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhf9NWKHjqE

Comment: This is also our [1000th question](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206/our-1000th-question), so congratulations on asking it

Comment: Thank you, the video had all my answers to this question. Btw, where can I find more videos, images, or wikis that show tongue diagrams of pronunciations of things? For Korean, maybe other languages too with IPA? @user17915

Comment: try searching our site or on youtube, I don't know about any off the top of my head

Comment: May be some of these are helpful: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=korean+pronunciation+tongue+diagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is frequently asked by many beginners of Korean language. In short, Korean consonants contain a lot of sounds :

네 [ne] = yes. Native English speaker may say 네 when his tongue is in the back of upper teeth.

But Korean speakers say it keeping their tongue in between upper
teeth and lower teeth. Hence it sounds like "de" (cf. "talk to me in korean" site)